# Load GLTF model from text

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently loading a GLTF file from a file served by a static file server.

```
  import * as THREE from 'three'
  import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';

  var loader = new GLTFLoader();

  loader.load(
    'http://localhost:1234/Assembly_PROD.gltf',
    function (gltf) {
      // Do stuff with loaded model
    },
    function (xhr) {
      // process progress
    },
    function (err) {
      // process error..
    }
  );
```

I'm now moving to an API server that provides GLTF files directly as text.
How can I load a GLTF file directly from its contents (and not through a file url) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) allows to drag&drop `glTF` files. It uses the `File` API to read the file contents and then directly calls `GLTFLoader.parse()` with the respective data.

```
reader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    var contents = event.target.result;

    var loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.parse( contents, '', function ( result ) {

            var scene = result.scene;

            // more code

    } );

}, false );
reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
```

When studying the code, you can see that an instance of `ArrayBuffer` is passed into `GLTFLoader.parse()`. However, this method also accepts string data.

`three.js R113`